# Can you modify the OWA redirection page in a hybrid O365 environment?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, outlook-web-app

In a hybrid Exchange environment, if you migrate a user mailbox and then they attempt to access the mailbox using the on-prem OWA (Outlook Web App) link, they will be presented with a page that instructs them to click another link to reach their mailbox and offers a button to create a favorite to the new OWA on O365. Can this redirection page be modified to change the wording, add branding or remove the button to add a favorite?

Answer (score 0):

Instructions are here:

https://www.allabout365.com/2012/04/enabling-silent-owa-redirection-for-office-365-hybrid/

The author of the above page states that this is an unsupported solution by Microsoft, so take backups before you make any changes!

Comment: Oh, just noticed, the above link is for Exchange 2010. So if that's what you have, then it will work. Otherwise if it's Exchange 2013 or 2016, you might have to mess around with error code redirects in IIS. Or take a look at this article, where you edit errorFE.aspx file on Exchange 2013.
https://parkerjardine.com/2016/02/05/silent-owa-redirection-for-exchange-2013-office-365-hybrid/

Comment: Yeah this will change the redirection URL but I don't want to change that. I want to modify the contents of that redirection screen (which I still want to see). That make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Sorry I didn't read your question correctly in the first place! I looked at the errorfe.aspx file and there's no easy way to customize that page. I believe it is a catch all for all errors on the frontend for OWA, so if you do find how to modify the contents, it would change it for all other errors that might arise for users.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the official document to simplify the Outlook Web App URL for Office 365 Hybrid
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/hybrid-deployment/simplify-owa-url

Comment: Yeah I believe that just changes the URL, not the redirection page. Thanks though.